# image resize with array of height and width

Tags: php, arrays, image, resize

i have an array of $h and $w. it will only create the `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['image']['name']);` how can i use the array of sizes in creating new images?

```
for ($resize=1; $resize <= $units; $resize++) 
     {  
        $new =  $album_name."_".$image_name."_".$resize.".".$image_ext;
        $targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($target));         
        imagecopyresampled($targetImage,$image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
        imagejpeg($targetImage,'uploads/'.$albumName.'/'.$new,80);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet `$w` and `$h` do not appear to be arrays.

Let assume that `$w` and `$h` are arrays of size `$resize` with different image sizes.

The following code also detects image MIME type using `getimagesize` function and resizes image of JPG, PNG and GIF formats.

```
for ($resize=1; $resize <= $units; $resize++) 
{
    $size = getimagesize($target);

    if ($size === false)
        return false;

    $format = strtolower(substr($size['mime'], strpos($size['mime'], '/') + 1));
    $icfunc = "imagecreatefrom" . $format;
    if (!function_exists($icfunc))
        return false;

    $new =  $album_name."_".$image_name."_".$resize.".".$image_ext;

    $targetImage = imagecreatetruecolor($w[$resize], $h[$resize]);
    $image = $icfunc($target);
    imagecopyresampled($targetImage,$image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w[$resize], $h[$resize], $originalWidth, $originalHeight);

    switch ($size['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpg':
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            return imagejpeg($dst_r, 'uploads/'.$albumName.'/'.$new, 80);
            break;
        case 'image/png';
            return imagepng($dst_r, 'uploads/'.$albumName.'/'.$new, 2);
            break;
        case 'image/gif';
            return imagegif($dst_r, 'uploads/'.$albumName.'/'.$new);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an input. which is $w = $_POST[width] and $w = $_POST[height]<input type="text" placeholder="Width" name="width[]" /><input type="text" placeholder="Height" name="height[]" />

Comment: @JethroAbarquez So what is `$resize`?

Comment: i used $resize to loop the values of the array

Comment: @JethroAbarquez you say in post that have an array of $h and $w, and then you say that `$w = $_POST[width]` and `$h = $_POST[height]`, so I don't understand you clearly